# Use both .babelrc and babel.config.js

Tags: babeljs

In the current project, I am employing expo, react-native and babel-plugin-module-resolver.

As the b-p-m-r doesn't support babel.config.js, I have to add .babelrc.

But in babel.config.js, I have statement of api.cache(true), which I want to keep.

So my question is, what if I maintain babel.config.js with only api.cache(true) and set plugin in .babelrc, will it work or what will happen?